# Invalid argument when running 'find' command with -exec and -mtime

Tags: find, exec, mtime

Pretty wierd error message came up on Centos.

I tried to run this command:

```
find /tmp/something -type f -mtime +2h -exec cp '{}' /tmp/target \;
```

And the error I've got:

```
find: invalid argument `-exec' to `-mtime'
```

Can the 'find' be different on other distributions?

Answer (score 5):

`-mtime` is used for days, if you need 2 hours check this:

```
find /tmp/something -type f -mmin +120 -exec cp '{}' /tmp/target \;
```

mmin specifies minutes so -mmin +120 will filter those more than 120 minutes ago (2 hours). From the manual:

> -mtime n
>
> File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.
>
> -mmin n
>
> File's data was last modified n minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

the `find` implementation on MacOS is a little bit different than the one available on Linux.
I believe you got the error above on a Linux system.

On Linux, `mtime` only accepts +- and a number. The number is the number of days.

For what you want to do above you have to use `mmin`

```
-mmin n
      File’s data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

This command should work on Linux:

```
find /tmp/something -type f -mmin +120 -exec cp '{}' /tmp/target \;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was a Mac vs CentOS issue. Thanks!